# SanDisk Cruzer Blade read only problem

Tags: usb, live-usb, gparted

I tried to make a bootable windows 10 drive using woeusb on this usb drive, but something went wrong with the writing process so i tried using gparted to delete the partitions but there was an error that popped up and now the usb is read only.

How can i fix this (if i can)?

Comment: When a thumb drive is suddenly 'read only' it *often* means that the device has in some way broken and the device is in that mode to prevent further damage. It's merely coincidental that it happened while performing the current task. It may not be broken and it may be recoverable. You can try some of the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/).

Comment: Try unmounting the device with Gnome-Disks, then try formatting with GParted.